# Can't Update from Appcenter

Tags: updates

This is the error shown:

**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-modules-nvidia-495-5.11.0-43-generic: Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-495 (<= 495.44-1) but 495.46-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed**

[image]

N.B: I uninstalled nvidia-driver-495 from appcenter and then tried updating again, but that didn't work.